# Minimal requirements for iPyWidgets package

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

What is the basic "stuff" needed in a pip package for it to be a custom iPyWidgets package that can be installed and will work as expected.

I've read the docs and looked at the 'cookiecutter' samples provided, but they put a bunch of build infrastructure around it such as webpack and yarn etc. that I don't want to use. I'm happy to 'roll my own' build infra using the tools I like (e.g. esbuild and maybe some hand-written files) if I know what the 'required end state' is for it to function properly.

Are there any docs or samples that just show the minimal files and required contents/functionality for an iPyWidget package?